# Are TIBS and TWEB in Alaska discontinued?

Tags: flight-planning, aim

My 2021 paper edition of FAR/AIM still mentions TIBS (7-1-8) as Alaska-Only, but when I look at the Alaska Chart Supplement I can't find any TIBS numbers.
https://aeronav.faa.gov/Upload_313-d/supplements/CS_AK_20211007.pdf

https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/

Answer (score 6):

Yes TIBS and TWEB were discontinued in Alaska on January 1, 2020 according to the [January/February 2020 edition of FAA Safety Briefing magazine](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/2022-01/JanFeb2020.pdf) and [FAASTeam notice NOTC9903](https://www.faasafety.gov/SPANS/noticeView.aspx?nid=9903).

> As part of FAA efforts to modernize and streamline service delivery, Flight Service will discontinue the Transcribed Weather Broadcast (TWEB) and Telephone Information Briefing Service (TIBS) in Alaska, effective January 1, 2020.

> The TWEB is a continuous broadcast of aeronautical and meteorological information over a limited network of Very High Frequency Omni-Directional Range (VORs) and Non-Directional Beacons (NDBs) across Alaska.  A similar broadcast service, the Hazardous Inflight Weather Advisory Service, known as HIWAS, is being discontinued in the contiguous United States (CONUS).

> TIBS is a continuous telephone recording of meteorological information that pilots can access without going through a Flight Service specialist. TIBS was discontinued in the CONUS in September 2018.

The [July 16, 2020 revision of the AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim_chg_2_7_16_20.pdf) still mentioned TIBS and TWEB but those were removed from the AIM in the [December 31, 2020 revision](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim_chg_3_dtd_12_31_20.pdf).

> This change removes references to TIBS and TWEB as these services are no longer provided by Flight Service.

Your 2021 paper copy of the AIM was probably written using an older 2020 version of the AIM.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE! Nice answer to a question nobody else has addressed.

Comment: @RalphJ Thank you!